# How to extract pairs of (href, alt) wih python scrapy

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, scrapy

I have an html page `(seed)` of the form:

```
<div class="sth1">
    <table cellspacing="6" width="600">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="link1"><img alt="alt1" border="0" height="22" src="img1" width="92"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="link1">name1</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="link2"><img alt="alt2" border="0" height="22" src="img2" width="92"></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="link2">name2</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is loop into all `<tr>`'s and extract all `href, alt` pairs with python scrapy. In this example, I should get:

```
link1, alt1
link2, alt2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from the [`Scrapy Shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
In [1]: for cell in response.xpath("//div[@class='sth1']/table/tr/td"):
   ...:     href = cell.xpath("a/@href").extract()   
   ...:     alt = cell.xpath("a/img/@alt").extract()
   ...:     print href, alt

[u'link1'] [u'alt1']
[u'link1'] []
[u'link2'] [u'alt2']
[u'link2'] []
```

where `index.html` contains the sample HTML provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Scrapy's built-in [SelectorList](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.SelectorList) combined with Python's zip():

```
from scrapy.selector import SelectorList

xpq = '//div[@class="sth1"]/table/tr/td[./a/img]'
cells = SelectorList(response.xpath(xpq))

zip(cells.xpath('a/@href'), cells.xpath('a/img/@alt'))
=> [('link1', 'alt1'), ('link2', 'alt2')]
```